# Refresh same page with ajax with different data

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax

I have a web page with a form each time a form is submitted same page loads but with different data relevant to the query. On the back-end i am using python for finding data relevant to query.
I want to process all this with ajax as back-end process needs more time so i need to show status to the user i -e whats going on now in the system
Also the data returned is the same html file but with some other data. so how can i display it on the current page. It should not be appended to current html file. it is standalone

Anyone please give me a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery, which gives you a very simple way to do that:

`$.post( "yourpage.html", $('form').serialize() + "&ajax=true", function(response) {
    $('#results').html(response);
});`

Server side, detect if `ajax` is `true` and then return only the query results instead of the whole page. They will be saved in the element of `id="results"`. Replacing the whole page is generally not a good idea.

Comment: So how Python detact is there any ajax request? Any Code?

Comment: You are already handling the submitted form, if you use my example, then there will just be an additional form field with name "ajax". Read it in whatever way you are reading the other form fields.